# SOAP webservice client in Play Framework 2.5.1

Tags: web-services, soap, playframework, playframework-2.5

I'm trying to develop SOAP webservice client using Play Webservice API, but I cant figure out how to do this. I found link: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaWS
But i don't see any example code, how to use WSClient to consume SOAP webservice.
Any advice greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 2 ways to consume SOAP web services with Play (I have added 2 just for the sake of completeness)

1. **Using the Play WS module** (as you have tried) - as you are going to be working with XML, you can just call:

---

```
CompletionStage<Document> documentPromise = ws.url(url).get().thenApply(WSResponse::asXml);
```

Of course after you get the XML Document you can manipulate it in any way you want - for example with *XPath* or some other XML parsing mechanism:

```
String value = XPath.selectText("//value", yourXmlDocument);
Node node = XPath.selectNode("//node", yourXmlDocument);
```

---

2. **Using (a / you own) SOAP library** - you can provide your library as a dependency in the `build.sbt` file or you can just put it in the classpath of the Play project and then use it.
   Also take a look at *scalaxb* (http://scalaxb.org/sbt-scalaxb)

Comment: Hi, thanks for help, but i i have one more question. In your 1 example variable url should point on asmx file (e.g. http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx) or on specific webmethod (e.g. http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetCitiesByCountry). I've wrote following:
ws.url("http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetCitiesByCountry").setRequestTimeout(5000).setQueryParameter("CountryName", "Ukraine").get().thenApply(WSResponse::asXml) 
and CompletionFuture completed, there's any calls to this webservice and result document is null.

Comment: The URL should definitely point to the resource you are going to work with - so in your case to the GetCitiesByCountry operation. But then note that they require a `POST` request - so you have to use `.post()` instead of `.get()`

Comment: Hi, i changed my code to `CompletionStage<Document> responseStage =
                    ws.url("http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetCitiesByCountry").setQueryParameter("CountryName", "Ukraine").setRequestTimeout(5000).post("content").thenApply(WSResponse::asXml);` or `ws.url("http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetCitiesByCountry").setRequestTimeout(5000).post("CountryName=Ukraine").thenApply(WSResponse::asXml);` and now Play is throwing ` org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.`

Comment: Because this is some xml related error, i'm trying to produce `WSResponse` object (delete `thenApply`), and now as response i get `NettyResponse { statusCode=500 body=System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: text/plain.}`. Similiar responses are for `text/xml` and `application/soap+xml`

Comment: This is probably because SOAP is more complex than rest WS, you have to specify the called method using `SOAPAction` header on the HTTP request. In general I would advise against writing your own soap client, as there are open source reliable libraries.