# Call WSDL/SOAP Services in Play Framework Scala

Tags: scala, soap, playframework

I'm new to play framework & scala but i want to call WSDL/SOAP Services in play  , I wonder how can call a wsdl service like
http://www.example.com/webservice?wsdl
& send some parameters like this :
 (1324643,"Ali","khahli")
to method(action) with name for example :
requestscore
this is too easy in ruby/PHP/elixir but I can't Imagine this in Scala & Play.

Comment: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS

Comment: also, you may want to checkout http://scalaxb.org/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519605/soap-webservice-client-in-play-framework-2-5-1